# Is it possible to consume a script UTxO in the same block?

Tags: script-addresses, redeemer

Let's say I lock some ADA at a script address. Someone who knows the redeemer value can unlock this ADA. Is it possible to include a redeeming tx in the same block as the tx which locks the ADA at the script address? Provided that the script tx was first in the mempool? Or is it necessary to wait at least for 1 confirmation before the ADA can be unlocked from the script address?

Answer (score 1):

If the first output is in the mempool, you can use it in a subsequent transaction without the node throwing an error. However, there is no assurance that both transactions will be part of the same block.

Comment: When would be such case that both the transactions wouldn't be included in the same block? For example under heavy blockchain load?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact scenario, I believe it works like first come first serve basis, so    all trxs in mempool may not fit in one block